# How to convert LocalDate from one format to another LocalDate format in java 8 without using String date?

Tags: java, string, date, formatting, localdate

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("date :" + date );//default format is yyyy-MM-dd
System.out.println(date.getClass().getName());//java.time.LocalDate
```

How to format the above `date` in `LocalDate` type with the format 
`dd-MM-yyyy`. But you can use String date pattern i.e `dd-MM-yyyy`. The output should be of `LocalDate` type only.

Comment: You can't without using String date! `date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))`

Comment: You cannot change the behaviour of the method `LocalDate.toString()` because the type `LocalDate` is final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not a responsibility of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class which is an immutable date-time object that represents a date. Its duty is not to care about the String format representation.

To generate or parse strings, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
String string = date.format(pattern);
```

Back to `LocalDate`, use the same pattern:

```
LocalDate dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(string, pattern);
```

But the new `dateParsed` will again be converted to its default String representation since `LocalDate` overrides [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) method. Here is what the documentation says:

> The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd.

You might want to implement your own decorator of this class which handles the formatting.

Comment: So to format from one to another format in LocalDate itself not possible ?

Comment: Do we need  LocalDate -> String (for formatting) -> LocalDate ?

Comment: Right, it's not possible. `LocalDate` represents the date itself, not it's format. To display the date in a different format (ex. `"dd-MM-yyyy"`), you have to format it using `DateTimeFormatter` and the produced result will be `String`. When you parse the very same `String` using the same pattern, you'll get `LocalDate` again - but `System.out.println("date :" + date );` will print exactly the same - its default representation.

Comment: Tip: Rather than hard-code a formatting pattern, you have *java.time* automatically localize by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.